# Invalid character error on YouTube-API for keywords/tags (when there's no invalid characters)

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-api, gdata-api

I've been trying to make a script that uploads YouTube videos to my channel and I wanted to have a progress bar on the upload so instead of directly using the YouTube API I've been trying to modify this script: http://code.google.com/p/youtube-upload/wiki/Readme to allow being called directly from another script instead of command line.

You can view my current version of the script here: http://pastebin.com/3BpTHBXm

The error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "youtube_upload.py", line 606, in <module>
    print upload_youtube_video("youtube@email.com", "password", "This is a test title", "this is a test description", "Games", "test tag, I like tagging, tagging is fun", "/root/test video.mp4")
  File "youtube_upload.py", line 594, in upload_youtube_video
    url = upload_from_script(email, password, title, description, category, keywords, file_path)
  File "youtube_upload.py", line 588, in upload_from_script
    return run_main(parser, options, args)
  File "youtube_upload.py", line 454, in run_main
    url = upload_video(youtube, options, video_path, len(args), index)
  File "youtube_upload.py", line 371, in upload_video
    data = youtube.get_upload_form_data(*args, **kwargs)
  File "youtube_upload.py", line 204, in get_upload_form_data
    post_url, token = self.service.GetFormUploadToken(entry)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gdata/youtube/service.py", line 721, in GetFormUploadToken
    raise YouTubeError(e.args[0])
gdata.youtube.service.YouTubeError: {'status': 400, 'body': "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><errors><error><domain>yt:validation</domain><code>invalid_character</code><location type='xpath'>media:group/media:keywords/text()</location></error></errors>", 'reason': 'Validation Failed'}
```

I've been trying to figure out what's wrong with it, and from what I can gather from the error message there's an invalid character in keywords, but printing the keywords value just shows the tags as you'd expect. No invalid characters (Youtube documentation says all valid UTF-8 characters are allowed)

I think it MAY be something to do with the encoding. Although I tried converting the string to UTF-8 and it made no difference (but perhaps I was doing it wrong? I used unicode(keywords, "UTF-8")

Another reason I think it might be to do with the encoding is I ran the script perfectly fine on my windows machine yesterday, but it doesn't work on my Linux machine that I'm using at the moment (I don't have access to my windows machine for a few days so I can't confirm whether it still works on the windows machine, I might have accidentally edited the code since then? I don't think I did though). So I'm thinking maybe it's something to do with how Linux encodes stuff compared to Windows? Just a wild guess.

P.S the only thing I edited about the script on pastebin was the username and password, so all the other data is still the same like the title, description and keywords.

Any help is really appreciated, if you need any more information from me just let me know.

Comment: I hate to beg, but does anything have any idea at all? I've been staring at the code for hours and I just don't have a clue where to start.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, just needed to strip the quotation marks.